# Как сделать сколько посетителей читали статью сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[tproger](https://tproger.ru/articles/sql-interview-questions?utm_source=tproger_after_post&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=live_blocks&utm_term=read_block)

Как сделать так , как на tproger или что-то похоже . Хочу сделать сколько посетителей посмотрел статью . Маленький глазок и рядом цифры  просмотренные  человеком

Comment: Скриптами никак думаю. Нужно чтобы просмотры записывались в базу данных и оттуда уже вытаскивать сумму.

Comment: у вас там целый ворох проблем с подсчетом. во-первых желательно считать количество клиентов просмотревших статью, а не количество хитов. во-вторых огромное количество запросов будет от самых разных ботов, парсеров и краулеров. Их нужно фильтровать. Если Вы не понимаете хотя бы в каком-то приближении как это сделать, то вам проще поставить какое-нибудь стороннее решение со счетчиком просмтров.